# OCaml matching tuples

Tags: ocaml

```
let add_information info = match info with 
    (int * int * int) -> int + int + int
;;

let result = add_information (1, 2, 3);;

print_int result;; (* should print 6 here *)
```

I believe you can match tuples just like you can with lists. Just not sure of the exact format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate with `,`s:

```
let add_info = function
  | a, b, c -> a + b + c
```

Because tuple matching is irrefutable - that is, there is no way for a match to fail - you can also bind tuples with `let` or in a function argument:

```
let a, b, c = calc_tuple () in a + b + c
```

Comment: or match them within the functions arguments as in, `let add_information (a,b,c) = ...`

Answer (score 1):

you could also declare a new variable saying something like:

```
   let d,e,f = info in 
   d+e+f;;
```